# VBA How to change text color before you start typing in a text box in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In PowerPoint I have a text box with text already in it that is the color grey. I would like to add to that text box and make the new text color dark blue so you can see what is new.

I have tried to change the text box color but that changes the entire text box that color. I need for the new text to be the color dark blue

Comment: No code to share?

Comment: No.... I have a text box with a list of things and I want the user to be able to add to the list and the text to be defaulted to dark blue since the current list is grey. this will be a growing list each week that each new week the list will grow and the previous weeks will be the color grey I have figured out how to turn it all grey using VBA but not when a user wants to add new text to make it dark blue so they don't have to manually change the color each week.

Comment: this is what I have but it changes everything blue. could you provide the correct code? ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideNumber).Shapes("Text Box 6").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 139)

Answer (score 1):

Add a space to the end of the existing grey text - select it and set the font color to blue. When the user types additional text it will be blue.

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim nm
    For Each nm in Array("TextBox1","TextBox2","TextBox3")
        ResetFontColor ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(nm)
    Next s
End Sub

Sub ResetFontColor(shp As Shape)
    With shp.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = .Text & " "                  'add a space
        .Font.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)     'set all text to grey
        .Characters(Len(.Text), 1).Font.Color = vbBlue 'change font color of the space
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked out great! thank you so much!

Comment: Would there be a simple way to have it for multiple shapes such as text box 1 text box 2 and text box 3 and text box 4?  as seen in the code below?  ResetFontColor ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(Text box 1,text box 2 text box 3, text box 4)?

Comment: Added example of calling in a loop.  Or if you have a common substring in the textbox names you could loop over all shapes and only format shapes whose name contains (eg) "list"

Comment: this worked great thank you for your help!

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.